# Compute Engine Resources CPU Usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cpu-usage

I'm running a data processing job on Google Compute Engine and I noticed that while my process is at 100% CPU Usage, the total is more at like 12% CPU Usage.

[image]

Can someone explain the difference between the number for the PID and the number for total usage? Also, am I wasting compute resources since the total CPU Utilization is so low?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have?  One option from top command is to hit numeric "1" key and it will expand the CPUs.

Comment: I see. I have 8 CPU's. 1 is maxed out at 100% while the rest is at 0%. So it sounds like my data processing job would run at the same speed even if I only had 1 CPU?

Comment: It depends on the job, but I'm guessing this job is a single thread process which means it will only use a single vCPU. Even if you scale up, it won't make a difference,